# a little programa to create people

Tags: java

I want to make a program to create people and to show a list of such persons, but do not know if I am doing well and neither logic using "arraylist" to print the results anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

```
package person;
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    public int Id;
    public String Name;
    public boolean Show;
    public ArrayList people;

    public Person(
            int identificator,
            String thename,
            boolean showornot
            ){
        this.Id = identificator;
        this.Name = thename;
        this.Show = showornot;
    }

    public void InsertPerson(Person person, ArrayList list){
        this.people = list;
        list.add(person);
    }

}
```

The main:

```
package person;
import java.util.*;


public class Trying {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner stdin2 = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner stdin3 = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner stdin4 = new Scanner(System.in);

     ArrayList list_of_people;
     list_of_people = new ArrayList();


     int option = 0;
     int identificador = 0;
     String name = "";
     boolean show = true;    

    name = “Toni”;


         Person person1 = new Person(identificador, name, true);
         person1.InsertPerson (person1, list_of_people);
         Iterator ite = list_of_people.iterator();
         while(ite.hasNext()){
             System.out.println(list_of_people);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having?  What makes you think your code does not work?

Answer (score 5):

**Problem:** You are creating the arraylist "people" as a property of each "person" (Saying, each person has a list of people)

**Quickfix:**
Move `public ArrayList people;` to your **Trying** class.
Move  `public void InsertPerson(Person person, ArrayList list)` to your Trying class as well.

**Better fix:**
I recommend using a PeopleManager class - which contains the arraylist "people" and the InsertPerson method. Then, you use the **PeopleManager** in **Trying** to build your people list.

```
public class PersonManager
{
    ArrayList<Person> people;

  public PersonManager()
  {
      people = new ArrayList<Person>();
  }

  public void InsertPerson(Person person)
  {
      people.add(person);
  }     
}
```

Then, you can remove the arraylist from Person, and the method InsertPerson from Person. You'll need to create a PersonManager in your Trying class.

Comment: You can either use static attribute for the array, but I recommend this, since InsertPerson is not a Person logic method, I mean.. you can.. but it is not logic. Using a PersonManager or People class, something like he suggests.

Answer (score 1):

`public ArrayList people;` does not belong in the Person class. I would suggest using it your client code (the Trying class) or creating a class People that inherits from ArrayList. You can then add a InsertPerson function to that class if you wish.

I would also suggest using a ArrayList for your collection rather than an ArrayList. See a [generic collections tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html) here. You should also create getter/setter moethods instead of using public fields.

So, your classes would be:

```
public class Person { // ...

public class People extends ArrayList<Person> {
    public void InsertPerson(Person person) {
        this.add(person); 
    }
 // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What everyone else is saying is true, but I think theoretically your code should still work.  There is a problem with this line however...

```
while(ite.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(list_of_people);
}
```

You are outputting the whole list every iteration and probably infinite looping.  Change it to something like this...

```
while(ite.hasNext()){
    Person curPerson = (Person)ite.next(); 
    System.out.println(curPerson.Name);
}
```

A slightly more elegant solution is to ditch the iterator for a foreach loop...

```
for (Person person : list_of_people) {
    System.out.println(person.Name);
}
```